# Assignment and addJavascriptInterface: any way to intercept in java?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

If you have an Android WebView, and you add an interface to a java object using addJavascriptInterface, is there a way to have assignment handled by java?

JS:

```
javaObject.x = 10
```

Java:

```
??
```

This sort of thing works fine:

```
javaObject.setX(10)
```

but I'm trying to use an existing javascript codebase that has lots of calls using assignment, and ideally I'd like to make as few changes as possible to it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "assignment handled by java" ?

Is it simply that you want to pass a value from javascript to java by means of a class member assignment rather than a method call on the JavaScriptInterface object?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is yes, but I can't think of a way to edit the question to make it any more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
final class DemoJavaScriptInterface {  

    DemoJavaScriptInterface() {  
        // code here...
    }

    public int  X ;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't relate to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [WebView.addJavascriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), only the Java object's public methods are able to be accessed from JavaScript.  Meaning that you cannot assign a value to a class member variable in the Java object from within Javascript.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

For example :

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
   public int x;
   private int y;

   public void setY(int value) {
       y = value;
       Log.d("JavaScriptInterface", "setY = " + y);
   }  
}

...

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    ... 
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
    webView.loadUrl(myHtmlFile);
}
```

**Javascript that lives in *myHtmlFile*:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    Android.x = 10;  // this will not work

    Android.setY(1000);  // this will work!

</script>
```